# How to create/naming var dynamicaly?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hello for some reasons i need to create var dynamicaly.

Exemple

I have first an Array wich i want to use to "compose" my vars names

```
myArray:Array = new Array("aa","bb","cc");
```

In my final project this Array is created from a xml.

I want to do something like this, but doesn't work...

```
var ["myvar" + myArray[0]]:Sound = new Sound();
var ["myvar" + myArray[1]]:Sound = new Sound();
var ["myvar" + myArray[2]]:Sound = new Sound();
```

so it will be equal to write

```
var myvaraa:Sound = new Sound();
var myvarbb:Sound = new Sound();
var myvarcc:Sound = new Sound();
```

Anybody can guide me?

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach isn't a very good object oriented practice.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions :

1- Just create an object and attach properties:

```
var obj : Object = {};
obj.myvaraa = new Sound();
obj.myvarbb = new Sound();
obj["myvarcc"] = new Sound();

trace(obj.myvarcc);
trace(obj["myvarcc"]);
```

2- Make your class "dynamic" :

`public dynamic class MyClass`

And then you will abble to do :

```
this["myVarName"] = new Sound
```

Comment: Thank you very much... it save me hours ;)